# isconnected() return true though mysql server gone away in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am working on zend framework application.I am running one mail sending script on server.Somehow I am getting response after 5 minute from SMTP server in meanwhile mysql server has gone away due mysql wait time out setting.I have checked that connection is active or not. I have use

```
$db->isConnected();
```

but it always return true though mysql server gone away.I can't understand the meaning of isConnected.Anyone explain me how db connection works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual (emphasis mine):

> Since release 1.7.2, you could check you are currently connected to
>   the RDBMS server with the method isConnected(). This means that a
>   connection resource has been initiated and wasn't closed. **This
>   function is not currently able to test for example a server side
>   closing of the connection.** This is internally use to close the
>   connection. It allow you to close the connection multiple times
>   without errors.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html

In other words, this is tracking the connection state *as seen from your code* - "did I connect yet? did I disconnect already?", not from the perspective of the underlying TCP tunnel.

(What to do: technically, you should be catching the SQL exceptions anyway, so if this issue happens at a specific point, you could check for disconnection there (e.g. with `$db->query('SELECT 1')`), and re-connect if this exception is thrown.)

Comment: if it tracking connection state then why it always return connection is active?. From where it get active connection.I can't understand ""This function is not currently able to test for example a server side closing of the connection".Will you understand me it properly

Comment: As I have already written, it tracks what you are doing with the connection from your end, not what might happen between the network and the server - so that you don't double-open or double-close that connection. (Yes, it sucks, no, it's not fair; deal with it.)